# application rejection to the same reason before 2.23

Tags: ios, objective-c

Reasons

2.23: Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines or they will be rejected
2.23

We found that your app does not follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines, which is required per the App Store Review Guidelines.

In particular, we found that on launch and/or content download, your app stores 64 MB. To check how much data your app is storing:

- Install and launch your app
- Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage
- If necessary, tap "Show all apps"
- Check your app's storage

The iOS Data Storage Guidelines indicate that only content that the user creates using your app, e.g., documents, new files, edits, etc., should be backed up by iCloud.

Temporary files used by your app should only be stored in the /tmp directory; please remember to delete the files stored in this location when the user exits the app.

Data that can be recreated but must persist for proper functioning of your app - or because customers expect it to be available for offline use - should be marked with the "do not back up" attribute. For NSURL objects, add the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute to prevent the corresponding file from being backed up. For CFURLRef objects, use the corresponding kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute.

For more information, please see Technical Q&A 1719: How do I prevent files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes?.

It is necessary to revise your app to meet the requirements of the iOS Data Storage Guidelines. 
For discrete code-level questions, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. Please be sure to:

- include the complete details of your rejection issues
- prepare any symbolicated crash logs, screenshots, and steps to reproduce the issues for when the DTS engineer follows up.

For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please see Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS Application Crash Reports.

If you have difficulty reproducing this issue, please try testing the workflow as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/Technical Q&A QA1764: How to reproduce a crash or bug that only App Review or users are seeing.
and i set this function in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSString *pathCaches = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Caches"];
    NSString *pathTmp = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/tmp"];
    NSString *pathDocuments = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Documents"];

    [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathCaches]];
    [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathTmp]];
    [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathDocuments]];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask]);

    const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];

    const char* attrName = "com.mycompany.MyApp";
    u_int8_t attrValue = 1;

    int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
    return result == 0;
}
```

The .sqlite3 file is not downloaded so I putted it in /Documents and other pdf files and images are downloaded
and my application rejected with the same reason 
Is i forget something ???
Please help me

Thank You

Comment: What is the specific error message they're giving you? Are they complaining that you're storing data upon install that isn't user-generated?

Comment: Are you making @"/Documents" NOT to backup? in the 3rd addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL? Comment this out and submit again.

Comment: r3mus i edited my question

Comment: I don't think it is possible to skip documents directory. You should skip only the big files.

Comment: Andrea what do you mean about big files

Comment: @KenCheung is anything else i need to change ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to submit for iOS versions 5.0.1 and above, use the below code. I don't think that you need to skip cache and tmp directory from iCloud backup coz iCloud doesn't care about these directories.

```
+(BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL {

// First ensure the file actually exists
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[fileURL path]]) {
    NSLog(@"File %@ doesn't exist!",[fileURL path]);
    return NO;
}

// Determine the iOS version to choose correct skipBackup method
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

if ([currSysVer isEqualToString:@"5.0.1"]) {
    const char* filePath = [[fileURL path] fileSystemRepresentation];
    const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
    u_int8_t attrValue = 1;
    int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
    NSLog(@"Excluded '%@' from backup",fileURL);
    return result == 0;
}
else if (&NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL result = [fileURL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];
    if (result == NO) {
        NSLog(@"Error excluding '%@' from backup. Error: %@",fileURL, error);
        return NO;
    }
    else { // Succeeded
        NSLog(@"Excluded '%@' from backup",fileURL);
        return YES;
    }
} else {
    // iOS version is below 5.0, no need to do anything
    return YES;
}
}
```

If the data can be downloadable from Server,then  instead of saving your downloaded files to the Documents directory save them to the Cache directory which is a temp directory that don't get backed up to iCloud and can be randomly deleted by the OS on certain occasions.

Comment: Do you mean i replace this function Instead of my function ??

Comment: Do you mean this 
NSString *pathCaches = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Caches"];
    NSString *pathTmp = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/tmp"];
    NSString *pathDocuments = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Documents"];

    [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathCaches]];
    [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathTmp]];
    [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathDocuments]];

Comment: You need to skip Documents for sure if you are saving more files. So Keep this line : [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathDocuments]];

Comment: Thank You for you effort i`ll submit again
any way i will make your answer correct before receive result form apple hope it work fine :)

Comment: mavriks i did this NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:documentsDirectory]];

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
const char* attrName = "com.mycompany.MyApp";
```

Dont change the value with your bundle id, it should always be:

```
 const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
```

Comment: You can use @user3097889 solution, but have in mind that this must not be replaced with your bundle id.